# How can i print total amount in DataTable jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

> I'm using data table but I have problem I can't print total amount
>   like that

[image]

> But when I click the print button the show me the table like that

[image]

> Help me how can fix my problem

Comment: You should post your code as well that will he too help full

Comment: code.... code.... code....

Comment: can you please post your full code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data` function of datatable to get all data of a column then `sum` it.

```
var table = $('#tblProfit').DataTable({});

var arrSalePrice = table.column(1).data();
var totalSalePrice = parseFloat(arrSalePrice.reduce(function (a, b) { return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b); }, 0)).toFixed(2);

$("#tblProfit tfoot").find('td').eq(1).text(totalSalePrice);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/2420/) is a fiddle where i have get sum of third column.

Comment: I also have that but I want to print like that

Comment: Sir, you are right but I want to print the footer in print